# Why does a plain URI written in c++ code work?

Tags: c++

I put URI in code and the compiler will not throw any error, why (explain please)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    http://stackoverflow.com/
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Syntax highlighter should help you...`http:` is a label (then syntax is valid) and everything after `//` is a comment...

Comment: Put a `goto http` before `return 0` and see... ;)

Comment: Stop voting the question down, it is a legit question if you are a beginner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Identifier followed by : becomes a **label** in C++. Anything followed by // becomes a comment.